# How to Make Multiple Content Popups Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How to show different content for different buttons using jquery

```
<div id="output"></div>  
<div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay"></div>
<div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
<table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td class="web_dialog_title">Email this Article</td>
     <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
     </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">

content
</td></tr></table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);  
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $("#btnShowShare").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
    $("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
        HideDialog(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
            HideDialog(); 
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery?
Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Not so clear...

Comment: $(document).ready(function ()
   {
      $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
      {
         ShowDialog(false);
         e.preventDefault();
      });

   $("#btnShowShare").click(function (e)
      {
         ShowDialog(false);
         e.preventDefault();
      });

      $("#btnClose").click(function (e)
      {
         HideDialog();
         e.preventDefault();
    
      });

   $(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         HideDialog(); }
});

   });

Comment: Hi Ballu, welcome to StackOverflow. Look under your question and you'll see an **edit** link. To add more to your question, use that, not the comments :)  I went ahead and put your code in the question for you. As an aside, method names should begin with a lowercase letter, like `hideDialog()`. This keeps it from  getting confused with a class or a prototype. Good luck!

Comment: To get help on this, you'll probably need to show the function definition for hideDialog and showDialog.

Comment: thanks jmort, i am facing an error while updating the jquery .so i could'nt update

Answer (score 0):

I would put the `content` in a `div` element as such:
`<div id="myContent">content</div>`
Then in the script:
`$("#myContent").html("New content");`
In each function. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);  
        $("#myContent").html("Simple content");
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $("#btnShowShare").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false); 
        $("#myContent").html("Share content");
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
    $("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
        HideDialog(); 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
            HideDialog(); 
        }
    });  });
```

**Edit**

Here is what I would do with the code [you linked to](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6942119) in the comment (relevant parts):

```
  $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
  {
     $("#dialog").html("Simple");
     ShowDialog(false);
     e.preventDefault();
  });

  $("#btnShowModal").click(function (e)
  {
     $("#dialog").html("Modal");
     ShowDialog(true);
     e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: not works $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e)
      {
         ShowDialog(false);
        $("#btnShowSimple").html("email");
         e.preventDefault();
      });
$("#btnShowShare").click(function (e)
      {
         ShowDialog(false);
           $("#btnShowShare").html("hi");

         e.preventDefault();
      });
<div id="btnShowSimple">content 1</div><div id="btnShowShare">content 2</div>

Comment: What kind of elements are `btnShowShare` and `btnShowSimple`? Where does it appear?

Comment: <button type="button" id="btnShowSimple" value="Email" class="positive" >
        <img src="../css/bmail.png" alt="email"/> 
Email
 </button>
<button type="button" id="btnShowShare" value="Share" class="positive" >
        <img src="../css/share.jpg" alt="Share"/> 
Share
 </button>

Comment: It seems you gave the `div` and `button` elements the same ID?

Try giving each one a unique ID.

BY the way, code between two ` is formatted.

Comment: could you give me ur email please , so that i will mail entire code.

Comment: When you copy-paste that code - it doesn't work?

Sidenote: Thanks for sending the whole thing, you were keeping back *a lot* of information!

Comment: i dont know jquery ,i used the code ,it works for single popup and not working for multiple content popup's

Comment: The given jQuery opens the same dialog, either in modal mode, or as a simple box. It looks the same.

Comment: exactly ...so i changed the sample and model box content.and followed your instructions on jquery .. but it shows normal..:-(